# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/pool2/PooledObjectFactory

Tags: spring, hibernate, noclassdeffounderror

I am new to Spring. I'm using BasicDataSource

```
<bean id="myDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/MySQL"/>
        <property name="username" value="root"/>
        <property name="password" value="Root"/>
     </bean>

  <bean id="mySessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource"/>
    <property name="mappingResources">
      <list>
        <value>com/test/jdbcTemplate/employee.hbm.xml</value>
      </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
      <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect"> org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">yes</prop>
      </props>
    </property>
  </bean>
```

I have used hibernate-commons-annotations-3.0.0.ga.jar,commons-pool2-2.0.jar,commons-dbcp2-2.1.jar,mysql-connector-java-5.1.4.jar,hibernate-core-3.6.9.Final.jar.

I am getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeHibernateTemplateImpl' defined in class path resource [com/test/jdbcTemplate/EmployeeBean.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernateTemplate' while setting bean property 'hibernateTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateTemplate' defined in class path resource [com/test/jdbcTemplate/EmployeeBean.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mySessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mySessionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/test/jdbcTemplate/EmployeeBean.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/annotations/common/reflection/MetadataProvider
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1360)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at com.test.jdbcTemplate.EmployeeHibernateTemplateImplAssembler.main(EmployeeHibernateTemplateImplAssembler.java:17)
```

Comment: I don't get it, the exception in the stack-trace is indicating that there is a problem creating your Hibernate bean in EmployeeBean.xml yet your question title talks about a apache-commons issue ??

Comment: InStacktrace exception its showing:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/annotations/common/reflection/MetadataProvider
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)

Comment: well it looks like the hibernate-commons-annotations-3.0.0.ga.jar cannot be resolved/found, so try removing that from the classpath/project and trying again with <dependency>
 <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
 <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
 <version>3.2.0.Final</version>
</dependency>

Comment: also may need to run a maven clean install before adding updated hibernate-commons-annotations jar

Answer (score 8):

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-pool2 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-pool2</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

add this dependency

Comment: add this to your pom.xml, it seems org/apache/commons/pool2/PooledObjectFactory is missing.

Answer (score 6):

I think you missed this library https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-pool/download_pool.cgi